# How to get Katalon Execution Result on Jira?

Tags: jira, katalon

Crosspost from the main StackOverflow page:

I'm trying to integrate Katalon into Jira with the Jira extension, but the field in Jira is not appearing.

I followed the directions here: (https://forum.katalon.com/t/bdd-gherkin-field-for-jira-cloud/18599) for integration, however, I think the steps are out of date. Has anyone been able to make the Katalon Execution Results appear in Jira? I've also posted in the Katalon forums as well, (https://forum.katalon.com/t/katalon-execution-result/21770/2). Thanks.